# Is it safe to add indexes to a big MySQL production table with ALGORITHM=INPLACE and LOCK=NONE?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, alter-table

I have a production website with many records selected, updated or added in realtime. While doing some tests in local, I noticed a big improvement when I added an index on the `user_id` column of a table that currently contains around 2.000.000 records.

While investigating on the best way to alter my production table to add this index, I found that adding `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` and `LOCK=NONE` would not affect the website. My aim is to have no impact in production, so records can still be added / updated / selected while the table is changed.

I have MySQL 8.0.19 on my production server and the query would be the following :

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX user_id_idx (user_id), ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
```

Will this query run with no impact on the records in production?

Comment: While you are at it, let's see your `SELECT`.  A composite index _starting with_ `user_id` may be even better.